# Remove Button in ItemRenderer giving error

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, action, itemrenderer

I am using the following .as file as the component for an itemrenderer in a list. Basically each item is rendered in a TextInput and each TextInput has a remove button as you can see from the code. When clicking the remove button, I want to remove the selectedItem..so I am putting the function removeItem() in MainMxml.xml and calling it from the .as file.

However I am getting an error "Cannot access a method or property of a null object reference". Can you help me out with this error?

The .as file as follows:

```
package components {
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    import mx.events.FlexEvent;

    import renderers.TextInputRenderer;

    import spark.components.Button;
    import spark.components.TextInput;
    import spark.events.TextOperationEvent;

    public class ClearableTextInput extends TextInput {

        [SkinPart(required="true")]
        public var clearButton:Button;

        [Bindable]
        public var mainMxml:MainMxml;


        public function ClearableTextInput() {
            super();

            //watch for programmatic changes to text property
            this.addEventListener(FlexEvent.VALUE_COMMIT, textChangedHandler, false, 0, true);

            //watch for user changes (aka typing) to text property
            this.addEventListener(TextOperationEvent.CHANGE, textChangedHandler, false, 0, true);
        }

        private function textChangedHandler(e:Event):void {
            if (clearButton) {
                clearButton.visible = (text.length > 0);
            }
        }

        private function clearClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
            mainMxml.removeItem();


        }


        override protected function partAdded(partName:String, instance:Object):void {
            super.partAdded(partName, instance);

            if (instance == clearButton) {
                clearButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clearClick);
                clearButton.visible = (text != null && text.length > 0);
            }           
        }

        override protected function partRemoved(partName:String, instance:Object):void {
            super.partRemoved(partName, instance);

            if (instance == clearButton) {
                clearButton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clearClick);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

And the ItemRenderer is as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                autoDrawBackground="true" xmlns:components="components.*" width="100%">

    <s:layout> 
        <s:HorizontalLayout/> 
    </s:layout> 

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.core.EdgeMetrics;
            import mx.core.UIComponent;

            import skins.ClearableTextInputSkin;

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>


    <components:ClearableTextInput id="clearTxt" text="{data.label}" skinClass="skins.ClearableTextInputSkin" />

</s:ItemRenderer>
```

I am  also setting the clear button in the ClearableTextInputSkin which is shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:SparkSkin
        xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
        minWidth="100" minHeight="22"
        alpha.disabled="0.5"
        blendMode="normal">

    <fx:Metadata>
        [HostComponent("components.ClearableTextInput")]
    </fx:Metadata> 

    <!-- states -->
    <s:states>
        <s:State name="normal"/>
        <s:State name="disabled"/>
    </s:states>

    <!-- bg --> 
    <s:Rect id="border" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" radiusX="3">
        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor id="bgFill" color="#ffffff" />
        </s:fill>
        <s:stroke>
            <s:SolidColorStroke id="borderStroke" color="#333333" weight="1" />
        </s:stroke>
    </s:Rect>

    <!-- text -->
    <s:RichEditableText id="textDisplay" left="4" right="24" top="1" bottom="0"
            color="#333333"
            verticalAlign="middle" />



    <s:Button id="clearButton" right="4" verticalCenter="0" />

</s:SparkSkin>
```

Your help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer can be very very long :)

Starting with your code the problem is in line:

```
mainMxml.removeItem();
```

Your `mainMxml` instance is `null` and that's why you have your NPE (null pointer exception).

But the code in general shows that you currently don't understand Flex, especially data binding. And of course have problems with app's architecture.

First, your line:

```
[Bindable]
public var mainMxml:MainMxml;
```

doesn't do anything.

Data binding is just a way to listen changes of variable annotated with `[Bindable]` metatag. `[Bindable]` is not a kind of dependency injection but completely opposite of it.

So nobody set the value of your `mainMxml` field. And to tell the true, it is not the right way to try to inject value there. Instead of that, you should use [Observer design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) and fire event from your component:

```
package events {
    public class ClearableTextInputEvent extends Event {
        public static const PERFORM_CLEAR:String = "performClear";
        public function ClearableTextInputEvent(type:String) {
            super(type);
        }

    }
}
```

So now the component:

```
package components {
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    import mx.events.FlexEvent;

    import renderers.TextInputRenderer;

    import spark.components.Button;
    import spark.components.TextInput;
    import spark.events.TextOperationEvent;

    [Event(name="performClear", type="events.ClearableTextInputEvent")]
    public class ClearableTextInput extends TextInput {

        [SkinPart(required="true")]
        public var clearButton:Button;

        public function ClearableTextInput() {
            super();

            //watch for programmatic changes to text property
            this.addEventListener(FlexEvent.VALUE_COMMIT, textChangedHandler, false, 0, true);

            //watch for user changes (aka typing) to text property
            this.addEventListener(TextOperationEvent.CHANGE, textChangedHandler, false, 0, true);
        }

        private function textChangedHandler(e:Event):void {
            if (clearButton) {
                clearButton.visible = (text.length > 0);
            }
        }

        private function clearClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
            dispatchEvent(new ClearableTextInputEvent(ClearableTextInputEvent.PERFORM_CLEAR));
        }


        override protected function partAdded(partName:String, instance:Object):void {
            super.partAdded(partName, instance);

            if (instance == clearButton) {
                clearButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clearClick);
                clearButton.visible = (text != null && text.length > 0);
            }           
        }

        override protected function partRemoved(partName:String, instance:Object):void {
            super.partRemoved(partName, instance);

            if (instance == clearButton) {
                clearButton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clearClick);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Ok. Now our renderer. There we should use event bubbling to inform our list container (I suppose it is an instance of `MainMxml`) about need to remove row. We should create an event class for that.

NB. You can use the same event class but the problem is your `ClearableTextInput` component and item renderer have different responsibilities 
and `ClearableTextInput` can be used again in some other renderers. It is good practice to create different events for the different layers of your application for low coupling:

```
package events {
    public class RemoveRowEvent extends Event {
        public static const REMOVE_CURRENT_ROW:String = "removeCurrentRow";
        public function RemoveRowEvent(type:String) {
            super(type, true);
        }

    }
}
```

Now your renderer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                autoDrawBackground="true" xmlns:components="components.*" width="100%">

    <s:layout> 
        <s:HorizontalLayout/> 
    </s:layout> 

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.core.EdgeMetrics;
            import mx.core.UIComponent;

            import skins.ClearableTextInputSkin;

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>


    <components:ClearableTextInput id="clearTxt" text="{data.label}" skinClass="skins.ClearableTextInputSkin" performClear="dispatchEvent(new RemoveRowEvent(RemoveRowEvent.REMOVE_CURRENT_ROW))" />

</s:ItemRenderer>
```

And finally in your list's container (`MainMxml` instance I suppose):

```
…
addEventListener(RemoveRowEvent.REMOVE_CURRENT_ROW, onRowRemove);
…

private function onRowRemove(event:RemoveRowEvent):void {
    removeItem();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
}
```

I wrote this draft in the browser so please fix imports etc. by yourself :)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation Constantiner...I agree that I was a bit lost within the architecture. Now I can better understand it. Today you made me learn :)

Comment: However there is another serious issue with my component, since the itemrenderer are textInput, all are them laid as having the same width independent of the length of the data inside at each item.

Is this very difficult to achieve?

Comment: I suppose it is better to start another question for that :)

Comment: Ok I will formulate the question and ask it..I will however just need some guidelines that can help me do it myself :)